# Replace everything with spaces except line terminators

Tags: java, regex, newline

Is the following replacement guaranteed to leave the line terminators `\r\n` intact?

```
"Hello\r\nWorld".replaceAll(".", " ")
```

I'm not sure if the `DOTALL` flag can be globally specified for all regular expressions.

Would it be safer to write this instead?

```
"Hello\r\nWorld".replaceAll("[^\r\n]", " ")
```

Comment: You want `DOTALL` *off* for your case. And it is off by default. Anyway, with Java it is enough to try once and what you get is pretty much what you are guaranteed to get.

Comment: `"Hello\r\nWorld".replaceAll(".", " ")` would leave `\r\n` in original input.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik So there is no way to enable `DOTALL` globally, outside of a specific regular expression?

Comment: You can technically use `(?s)` at the beginning to enable it for the whole expression, but there is no such thing as setting a global option for all regular expressions created from that point on.

Comment: Yes, there is no global configuration to the Regex API---which, of course, is a very *good* thing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `.` and line separator

Since `.` considers `\r` and `\n` as line separator (among `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`<sup>1</sup>, `\u0085`, `\u2028`, `\u2029`), the line separator sequence `\r\n` or any sequence involving `\r` or `\n` naturally will not be matched by `.`.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Regarding `\r\n` line terminator sequence, more interesting behavior is observed when `$` is involved, since the engine needs to treat `\r\n` as an atomic line separator when backtracking.</sup>

### Set flags for a regular expression inline

You can specify any flag (except for `CANON_EQ`<sup>2</sup>) to be enabled for the whole regular expression, or even a portion of the regular expression, with `(?<flags>)` for the former case and `(?<flags>:<re>)` for the latter case. This is described under [**Special constructs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) section of `Pattern` class documentation.

The available flags are `i` (`CASE_INSENSITIVE`), `d` (`UNIX_LINES`), `m` (`MULTILINE`), `s` (`DOTALL`), `u` (`UNICODE_CASE`), `x` (`COMMENTS`), `U` (`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`, from Java 7).

The flags can be turned off prefixing a single `-` before all the flags to be turned off, as shown in the example in the documentation `(?idmsuxU-idmsuxU)` and `(?idmsux-idmsux:X)`.

<sup><sup>2</sup> The source code of Oracle's implementation reveals that `c` is the flag for `CANON_EQ`, but it is totally useless, since `CANON_EQ` is checked and processed before the regular expression is properly parsed (which is a bad thing in my opinion, and it evidently messed up so bad that it is unusable).</sup>

### Set flags for all regular expressions

If what you are looking for is a global option to specify that all regex compiled after the option is set will have certain flags set by default, then the answer is **no**, none available.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [the `Pattern` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> The regular expression `.` matches any character except a line terminator **unless** the `DOTALL` flag is specified.

So if you just use your first expression, it will work as you wish:

```
"Hello\r\nWorld".replaceAll(".", " ")
```

Comment: So there is no way to enable `DOTALL` globally, outside of a specific regular expression?

Comment: @FredOverflow One can only specify the flag when creating each `Pattern` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the implementation of String.replaceAll(), it uses Pattern internally without the DOTALL flag without reference to any global settings.

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement);
}
```

Pattern.compile(regex) passes 0 (no flags) into Pattern.compile(regex, flags), this disables the DOTALL mode.

```
public static Pattern compile(String regex) {
    return new Pattern(regex, 0);
}
```

Pattern can be used to manually add the DOTALL flag but defaults to not using it, this changes how an individual instance of Pattern behaves

A worked example:

```
String test = "Hello\r\nWorld";

System.out.println(String.format("With DOTALL >%s<",
        Pattern.compile(".", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(test).replaceAll(" ")));

System.out.println(String.format("Without DOTALL >%s<", 
        Pattern.compile(".").matcher(test).replaceAll(" ")));
```

Output

```
With DOTALL >            <
Without DOTALL >     
     <
```

Comment: OP doesn't really need DOTALL, he's just afraid of it can appear because of some settings in other code.

Comment: By the way, you can set DOTALL without explicit usage of `Pattern` with "(?s)" flag at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg That's exactly what I was worried about!

Comment: Surely adding "(?s)" to the beginning of your specific regex isn't a "global" setting, it's not something that other parts of your application could accidental do...